# Setting value of all input fields with X ID using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am using JS to set multiple forms which have the following hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="sGUID" id="sGUID" value="">
```

Using my JS function I use

```
document.getElementById("sGUID").value = "my value goes here";
```

The problem is this only sets the last instance of the `sGUID` to the value set. How can I ensure all of them are set to this?

Comment: That's because IDs **must** be unique. Perhaps use classes instead and iterate over them.

Comment: ids are supposed to be unique throughout the entire document. use a class or an attribute like `data-id` instead

Comment: Ids should be unique... use class names instead

Comment: How do you have multiple ids? You cant have multiple ids and try to access all. you will have problem

Comment: Why don't you set class names to the inputs and try with getElementsByClassName()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the same `id` value.

If you have `sGUID` as name values, try the below:

```js
var sGUIDs = document.getElementsByName("sGUID");

for (var i = 0; i < sGUIDs.length; i++) {
    sGUIDs[i].value = "my value goes here";
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="sGUID" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sGUID" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="sGUID" value="3">
```

Comment: Note: It's a bad practice to use `.length` directly on the comparison. Why ? Because here, `.length` is executed on every iteration (not good for performance). And if you change the length of the array you can create an infinite loop !  It's better to create another variable and put the length into.

Answer (score 3):

Use classes as IDS must be unique and loop through them.

```js
let guids = document.getElementsByClassName("sGUID");
let newstring = "string";
for(let z = 0;z < guids.length;z++){
   guids[z].value = newstring;
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="sGUID" class="sGUID" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="sGUID" class="sGUID" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="sGUID" class="sGUID" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="sGUID" class="sGUID" value="">
```

Comment: Note: It's a bad practice to use `.length` directly on the comparison. Why ? Because here, `.length` is executed on every iteration (not good for performance). And if you change the length of the array you can create an infinite loop ! It's better to create another variable and put the length into.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and loop to change all inputs value

```
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="sGUID"]');
for(let l = inputs.length;l--;){
   inputs[l].value = "my value goes here";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a rewrite of @zmag's response, just in shorthand.

```
document.getElementsByName('sGUID').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
   ele.value = 'TESTVALUE';
})
```